# Rendering html tag after tap using flutter_html_iframe package

Tags: html, flutter, dart, html-parsing

I have a HTML document and I want to render it with Flutter using `flutter_html_iframe` plugin.
On default I want to be visible a button. When user tap it, the rendered iframe (an yt movie) shall be visible.

I have tired to create custom renderer as mentioned at https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_html_iframe/latest/. But it appears it only can set `navigationDelegate` value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.